# How to generate listitem in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to write simple web app for generating .config files. My problem is with large number of radiobuttonlists with same t/f options. Is it possible to change this:

```
EnableDatabaseTask
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="EnableDatabaseTask" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="true"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value ="false"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
EnableSMPPTask
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="EnableSMPPTask" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="true"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="false"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
EnableM2MTask
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="EnableM2MTask" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="true"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="false"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Into something like this:

```
EnableDatabaseTask
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="EnableDatabaseTask" runat="server">
    <% boolListItems() %>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
EnableSMPPTask
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="EnableSMPPTask" runat="server">
    <% boolListItems() %>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
EnableM2MTask
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="EnableM2MTask" runat="server">
    <% boolListItems() %>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I have no idea how can I make function in code behind which I would be able to call to fill list items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a general method in codebehind and pass `RadioButtonList` to it:

```
private void GenerteTrueFalseListItems(RadioButtonList radioButtonList)
{
    radioButtonList.Items.Clear();
    radioButtonList.Items.Add(new ListItem("True","True"));
    radioButtonList.Items.Add(new ListItem("False","False"));
}
```

And call this method multiple times from `page_load`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       GenerateTrueFalseListItems(EnableDatabaseTask);
       //and more radiobutton lists
       //GenerateTrueFalseListItems(Name_Of_Your_RadioButtonList);
    }
}
```

No need to do anything in HTML to add list items

Comment: Thank you, but... Where can I add specific IDs by which I will be able to pull data from app after user selected options?

Comment: This suggestion is according to your HTML.. you are showing true, false only in HTML.. what kind of ID you want?. You need to modify your question to reflect your actual problem @Kajbo

Answer (score -1):

You may add these true/false items on page load. Just define an array of RadioButtonList and add these radiobutton lists to your array. After that, you can do things like: (pseudo-code)

```
foreach (var rbl in myRadioButtonListArray)
{
   rbl.Items.Add("True","True");
   rbl.Items.Add("False","False")
}
```

Comment: I think this would not work because every RadioButtonList have it's own ID

Comment: I did not mention a one-time task you should do on purpose. Just initialize your array with your radiobuttonlists. eg:

`var myRadioButtonListArray = new RadioButtonList[]{EnableDatabaseTask,EnableSMPPTask,EnableM2MTask};`